# Not getting desired output in string concatination

Tags: c, string

**This is my code and i am not getting expected result as the output is able to print first string and concatenating but not the second string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[30],str2[30];
    printf("Enter Srting 1:");
    gets(str1);
    printf("Enter string 2: ");
    gets(str2);
    concat(&str1,&str2);
    printf("New string is: %s",str1);
    return 0;
}
void concat(char* str1,char* str2)
{
    int i,j;
    i=j=0;
    while(str1[i]!='\0')
    i++;
    while((str1[i++]=str2[j++]!='\0'))
    ;
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting and what output are you receiving?

Comment: Never use `gets`! it is recipe for buffer overrun.

Comment: If you think any answer help you solved your problem, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you problem is still unsolved, consider [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard any more. So it is better to use either `scanf` specifying the width of the inputed data of `fgets` funcions

Nevertheless the function can look the following way

```
char * concat( char* str1, const char* str2 )
{
    int i,j;
    i=j=0;
    while( str1[i]!='\0' ) i++;
    while( ( str1[i++] = str2[j++] ) !='\0' );

    return str1;
}
```

Or you could just write

```
    while( ( str1[i++] = str2[j++] )  );
```

Without parentheses expressiin

```
( str1[i++] = str2[j++] !='\0' )
```

is equivalent to

```
( str1[i++] = ( str2[j++] !='\0' ) )
```

And the function should be called like

```
concat( s1, s2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
while((str1[i++]=str2[j++]!='\0'))
```

by

```
while( (str1[i++] =str2[j++]) != '\0)
```

and

```
concat(&str1,&str2);
```

by

```
concat(str1, str2);
```

Comment: You compiler should give some warnings if you compile with warning enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `concat` code is incorrect:

```
while((str1[i++]=str2[j++]!='\0'))
```

should be

```
while ((str1[i++] = str2[j++]) !='\0')
```

You should always use spaces around binary operators to improve readability!

Furthermore, `concat` should be declared or defined before use and it should be invoked as `concat(str1, str2);` as `str1` and `str2` are arrays.

It is unwise to use `gets()` because it can cause buffer overflows, especially when receiving input from an external source.